# how can i print CMB2 field type?

Tags: wordpress

I didn't able to print the selected category in the front end
My back end code is

```
array(
                'name'      => 'Test Taxonomy Multicheck',
                'desc'      => 'Description Goes Here',
                'id'        => 'wiki_test_taxonomy_multicheck',
                'taxonomy'  => 'category', //Enter Taxonomy Slug
                'type'      => 'taxonomy_multicheck',
                // Optional :
                'text'      => array(
                    'no_terms_text' => 'Sorry, no terms could be found.' // Change default text. Default: "No terms"
                ),
            )
```

and my front end code is

```
<?php 
            $tax_chec = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wiki_test_taxonomy_multicheck',true);
            echo $tax_chec;

         ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually CMB2 taxonomy multicheck behaves as native WordPress taxonomy widget - it is not custom field as you think. So if you check something in your wiki_test_taxonomy_multicheck "custom" field the same values will be selected inside your Category widget. To retrieve selected values use `wp_get_post_terms` (ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```